# Can not boot ubuntu into default mode

Tags: boot, default, mode

I'm newbie with ubuntu, when I start up Ubuntu, my Ubuntu can not boot into default mode and I received massage following message.

[image]

Please help me, Thanks you so much.

Comment: Run command `systemctl default` first & then see what happen.

Comment: Ubuntu loading screen appears. After that it still displays this massage console screen again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck in emergency mode you can try to go back to default by using

Run this in root

```
sudo -i 

sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
dconf reset -f /dev/sda8/ && setsid unity
```

Replace / with output on emergency mode preview.

This may require a reboot.

Comment: I received a error after the second conmmand:
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Usage:
   dconf reset [-f] PATH

Reset a key or dir. -f is rquired for dirs.
.....

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full output of the error plz

Comment: Ok, this is full output.
Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY 
Usage: dconf reset [-f] PATH 

Reset a key or dir. -f is rquired for dirs.
Arguments:
PATH:     Either a KEY or DIR
KEY        A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
DIR         A directory path (starting and ending with '?').

Comment: Sorry, How can i put my command in box like you, I am newbie and just joined this forum a day ago :)

Comment: O isee you used the example my apologizes updated answer.

Comment: @DnrDeviI, thanks for your patient,I did like your direction, but i still receive output same as my previous comment, it is "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY...".